# Solution set of linear equation with restraint

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are integers and the restraint is given as 
$$
1 \leq x_{1} \leq 5\,,\quad 4 \leq x_{2} \leq 9\,,\quad
6 \leq x_{3} \leq 11\,,\quad10\leq x_4\leq 15
$$

What is the number of solutions to this linear equation ?.

Comment: What possible value for $x_3$, $x_2$, and $x_1$ if $x_4 = 11$...what if $x_4 = 12$, $x_4 = 13$...etc?

Comment: I am quite sure that I can get the answer if I discuss case by case...but is there a more generalised, more elegant way of solving this question?

Comment: Well there is a pattern that each of $x$'s range along $5$ numbers but they overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given by the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in $A(x)\cdot B(x)\cdot C(x)\cdot D(x)$ where
$$A(x)=(x^1+x^2+x^2+x^4+x^5),\quad B(x)=(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9)\\C(x)=(x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}+x^{11}),\quad D(x)=(x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+x^{13}+x^{14}+x^{15})$$
That is also the coefficient of $x^9$ in $E(x)\cdot F(x)\cdot G(x)\cdot H(x)$ where
$$ E(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4),\quad F(x)=G(x)=H(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$$ hence it is enough to compute
$$ [x^9]\frac{(1-x^5)(1-x^6)^3}{(1-x)^4} $$
and since $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+3}{3}x^n $$
the answer is given by
$$\binom{9+3}{3}-\binom{4+3}{3}-3\binom{3+3}{3} = 220-35-60 = \color{red}{\large 125}.$$

Comment: shouldn't the power of 1-x^6 be raised to 3?

Comment: @user122049: you are clearly right. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is akin to putting 30 identical balls in 4 distinct boxes

Put 1 in the first, 4 in the second, 6 in the third and 10 in the fourth, 9 more remain to be put.

Allotments in which you put $\ge 5$ in the first box and $\ge6$ in the others will be invalid.
[ Note that with the given figures, you can violate the constraints in only one box]

Applying [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) with [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we get

$\binom{12}3 - \binom73 - \binom31\binom63 = 125$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 30\implies y_{1} + y_{2} + y_{3} + y_{4} = 9
\\[2mm] &\
\mbox{where}\quad
0 \leq y_{1} \leq 4\,,\quad 0 \leq y_{2} \leq 5\,,\quad
0 \leq y_{3} \leq 5\,,\quad 0\leq y_{4}\leq 5
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\sum_{y_{1} = 0}^{4}\sum_{y_{2} = 0}^{5}\sum_{y_{3} = 0}^{5}
\sum_{y_{4} = 0}^{5}\bracks{y_{1} + y_{2} + y_{3} + y_{4} = 9} =
\sum_{y_{1} = 0}^{4}\sum_{y_{2} = 0}^{5}\sum_{y_{3} = 0}^{5}
\sum_{y_{4} = 0}^{5}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{1 \over z^{10 - y_{1} - y_{2} - y_{3} - y_{4}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{1 \over z^{10}}\sum_{y_{1} = 0}^{4}z^{y_{1}}
\pars{\sum_{y = 0}^{5}z^{y}}^{3}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{1 \over z^{10}}{z^{5} - 1 \over z - 1}\pars{z^{6} - 1 \over z - 1}^{3}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 - z^{5}}\pars{1 - z^{6}}^{3} \over z^{10}\pars{1 - z}^{4}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 0}^{3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{3 \choose m}{-4 \choose n}
\pars{-1}^{m + n}
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}\bracks{z^{6m + n - 10} - z^{6m + n - 5}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 0}^{3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{3 \choose m}{n + 3 \choose 3}\pars{-1}^{n}
\pars{-1}^{m + n}
\braces{\vphantom{\large A}\bracks{n = 9 - 6m} - \bracks{n = 4 - 6m}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 0}^{1}{3 \choose m}{12 - 6m \choose 3}\pars{-1}^{m} -
\sum_{m = 0}^{0}{3 \choose m}{7 - 6m \choose 3}\pars{-1}^{m} =
{12 \choose 3} - {3 \choose 1}{6 \choose 3} - {7 \choose 3}
\\[5mm] = &\
220 - 3 \times 20 - 35 =
\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px groove navy]{\ds{125}}
\end{align}